# Hide an empty row of a table with <h4> in HTML

Tags: css, html, html-table

I would like to know how to hide a row in HTML. Using the CSS method of `style="empty-cells : hide;"` seems to work, but if the `<h4>` tag is included in the empty table, then the row is not hidden.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>

<form name="form_simple" action=" " method="get">
<table border="1px" style="empty-cells : hide;">
<tr><td><h4>Empty cells should not have any borders around them</h4></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><h4>Empty cells should not have any borders around them.</h4></td></tr>
<tr><td><h4>Empty cells should not have any borders around them.</h4></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`style="empty-cells : hide;"` works for `<tr><td></td></tr>`, but not for `<tr><td><h4></h4></td></tr>`

Comment: yes it's acceptable. Any help?

Comment: In fact I just tested your code ( http://jsfiddle.net/qHGV5/ ) and it seems the cells with just an empty h4 are hidden too. So I'm not sure I get the question.

Comment: @dystroy it does show. there are 2 borderlines

Comment: @Chanckjh But that's the same with or without the h4 tag. For me it's unrelated.

Comment: Check this [fiddle][1]. If you remove the text from <h4> tag it is also hiden. So what is the solution you want. 


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/qHGV5/

Comment: @dystroy Uncheck "Normalized CSS" and re-run the fiddle and you should notice the different.

Comment: An element is not empty if it contains an element. So what do you want? On which basis should some rows be hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a work-around:

```css
table td {
    background-color:olive;
    empty-cells:hide;
}
table td > *:empty {
    display:none;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qHGV5/1/)

Change `*` to `h4` if you only want to target `h4`.

Note that according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/empty-cells), `empty-cells` should apply to *table-cell* element, not *table* (although browsers seem to accept it anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using javascript :

```
var rows = ​document.get​ElementsByTagName('tr');
​​​​for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
    var t = rows[i].innerText || rows[i].textContent;
    if (t.trim().length==0) rows[i].style.display='none';
}​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/WHGGz/)